# Add class to first field in fields views

Tags: entities, 8

How to add class to first fields in views?

I think that I need to add one if but I dont know what argument to put in if...

So how to add class just for first field in views-view-fields template.

```
{% for field in fields -%}
{%
        set colors = [
        'color-'~cycle(["red","yellow"],loop.index),
        loop.first ? 'first',
        loop.index== "1"?'color-first',
        ]
%}
        <b {{ field.element_attributes.addClass(colors) }}> {{ field.content }}</b>
{%- endfor %}
```

This code do this :

[image]

Comment: Why not add this in the view itself? You can add classes to the field wrapper, field label and field content of a views field itself. You can also change the HTML element that each of those use to be whatever you want.

Comment: `first fields` as in the first row only?

Comment: you want to add a class of red and yellow?

Comment: I want to have class first for first field and that red and yelow alternating turns.

Comment: you want row 1 to be red, row 2 to be yellow, row 3 to be red, row 4 to be yellow...etc.. ??

Comment: Yes and also for 1 field have class first.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by using loop.first. The joke was that in

**views-view-unformatted.html.twig** add loop.

```
{% for row in rows %}
    {% if loop.first %}
       <b class="is-visible">{{ row.content }}</b>
    {% else %}
       <b> {{ row.content }}</b>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And the code in **views-view-fields.html.twig** stay normal.

```
 {% for field in fields -%}
        {{ field.content }}
{%- endfor %}
```

On this way you add class to first field of fields.

Answer (score 4):

You can use preprocess field hook which is supported in drupal 8 also .
Example below:

```
function example_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
    if (($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'example')) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'] = [
     'example'
      ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Why code when you can do this using the Views UI?

Comment: Code is beter, because if somebody look for 2 years my code he would know where to found that class. Views UI is not good idea, because people forget to look there. Thank for sugestion to use preprocess field hook. But I would like to to this with twig, if I found how. Its somethinkg new and I would like to learn to use that in drupal 8.